# How to signup and set the child data for multiple user using loop of javascript in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, loops, firebase-authentication

I need to sign up in firebase for multiple users with their email and password. In the same time,I have to save their data like email, name, designation in firebase database.

I was doing it in javascript, their datas in array and using loop. Signing up is ok. But, there is something wrong with setting the datas. only the last index works.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
  handleSignUp(emails[i], pass[i]);
  saveToDatabase(names[i], phones[i], des[i], emails[i]);
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}

function handleSignUp(email, password) {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}

function saveToDatabase(name, phone, designation, email) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      var uid = user.uid;
      firebase.database().ref().child('user/' + uid).set({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        designation: designation,
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I need to save all data.But, only last data is being saved. Though `handleSignup()` works fine. How can i fix it?

Comment: Also, `onAuthStateChanged` is an event listener... you only need to set it up once and it's called automatically when the auth state changes.

Comment: `saveToData` is typo! That's not the issue! And as you say, I don't need to call this method right? How can I pass the data in this event listener?

Comment: well, I've done it. but, this time I got the the 1st and last index only.